# Android New Apps Work On Old Versions

Tags: android, eclipse

I am planning to study on Android programming. Now, I installed Eclipse and downloaded latest SDK. I will make apps on Android 5 because it installed Android 5 SDK but I wonder if these apps can work on older versions. My phone is Android 4.4 so if I make an app now, will it work on my phone?

By the way, book I am studying was published on 2014, it works on Eclipse. I noticed that Google released Android Studio. Do you guys suggest Android Studio instead of Eclipse?

Comment: `will it work on my phone?` You have to set the `minSdkVersion` to **19**. Also download the missing SDKs (19, 20). `Do you guys suggest Android Studio instead of Eclipse?` **Not me**. I still love Eclipse.

Comment: **You need to switch to Android Studio**. [The eclipse plug-in is no longer in active development](http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-releases-android-studio-kills-off-eclipse-adt-plugin/). It's nearly abandon-ware and will be completely killed off in short order.

Comment: No, no... I really **don't need to switch**!

Answer (score 1):

You should put in your manifest something like this:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"  />
```

which means that your app targets android 5,  but it can be installed on lower versions too, in this case api 14 means android 4.0 and api 21 means - android 5. 

 Keep in mind that it only refers to Eclipse. 

Choosing IDE is left to your discretion.

Comment: This is very similar to my comment, though.

Comment: Sorry, i haven't noticed your comment. I'll keep in mind that for the next time. Is here any race, competition for something? I mean did you lose anything because of my answer?

Comment: Well, it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to help a person and I got negative reaction for that.

Comment: It seems to me that you got a positive reaction, instead. At least a +1. And maybe more.

Comment: I'm not for points here. Anyway ,my bad if I said anything wrong. Take care.

Comment: You didn't say anything wrong. You just posted as an answer something I posted as a comment some minutes before. Just pay attention not to post double contents.

Comment: Both answers helped me a lot. This one showed answer inside the code so it was really useful, thanks!